# passwords on restricted accounts (KitKat)

Tags: password, restricted-profiles, password-protection

I created a restricted account on a nexus 7 (gen1) with KitKat for my 9y/o daughter.

She has worked out how to add a password to the restricted account. I understood it wasn't possible to this, but seems I was wrong.

Q. Is it possible to retrieve the password from the main account?

Q. Is it possible to prevent a password being applied to the restricted account?

Comment: It seems that restricted users can add a 'screen lock' in the 'security' page in 'settings' - an of feature to leave to the restricted user!